# Jenkins "github organization" without Jenkinsfiles - Possible?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-github-plugin

We are using the github organization plugin to automatically discover and build a large set of repositories.

These repos should all run the exact same pipeline and we would like to have control over it on the devops level. I.e. not having the Jenkinsfile exist in the individual repositories.

I have thought about using shared libraries to share the logic but the main hurdle is to remove the pipeline definition all together from the individual repositories. Scripted pipelines seems not to be available for this project type.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: Its been years and I don't rely remember but I know we went with a shared library and I THINK a one liner in the individual jenkinsfiles.